# Reset Password - change from name and email address

Tags: email, wp-mail, password

When the password reset goes out, the name is 'WordPress' and the from address is wordpress@domain.com.  I need to change these to the company name.

I'm running WordPress 3.8 multisite and have done the following:

- Updated general settings name and email address for the subsite
- Installed 'WP Change Email' plugin and updated the details

However, this has no effect.  I think its because the password reset side of things uses different hooks.

I'm using the following code (from http://s14.codeinspot.com/q/2472332) in functions.php to customise the password reset title and body:

```
function my_retrieve_password_subject_filter($old_subject) {
    // $old_subject is the default subject line created by WordPress.
    // (You don't have to use it.)

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
    $subject = sprintf( __('[%s] Password Reset'), $blogname );
    // This is how WordPress creates the subject line. It looks like this:
    // [Doug's blog] Password Reset
    // You can change this to fit your own needs.

    // You have to return your new subject line:
    return $subject;
}

function my_retrieve_password_message_filter($old_message, $key) {
    // $old_message is the default message already created by WordPress.
    // (You don't have to use it.)
    // $key is the password-like token that allows the user to get 
    // a new password

    $message = __('Someone has asked to reset the password for the following site and username.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url() . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('To reset your password visit the following address, otherwise just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n";

    // This is how WordPress creates the message. 
    // You can change this to meet your own needs.

    // You have to return your new message:
    return $message;
}

// To get these filters up and running:
add_filter ( 'retrieve_password_title', 'my_retrieve_password_subject_filter', 10, 1 );
add_filter ( 'retrieve_password_message', 'my_retrieve_password_message_filter', 10, 2 );
```

However, I don't know how to extend this to change the from name and email address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following two hooks to change name and email address

Use the following in your active theme's **`functions.php`** file.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wpse_new_mail_from' );     
function wpse_new_mail_from( $old ) {
    return 'your email address'; // Edit it with your email address
}

add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'wpse_new_mail_from_name');
function wpse_new_mail_from_name( $old ) {
    return 'your name or your website'; // Edit it with your/company name
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following code in your active theme's `functions.php` file. No need to hard code your email address and blog name, this gets both as given in WordPress Settings > General.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name' );
function new_mail_from( $old ) {
    return get_option( 'admin_email' );
}
function new_mail_from_name( $old ) {
    return get_option( 'blogname' ); 
}
```

Comment: The right way to do it.